# График типа heatmap в Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть двумерный массив numpy, представляющий собой набор значений некоего параметра. Часть данных в этом массиве пропущена и имеет тип numpy.nan.

Я бы хотел построить график типа "теплокарта" используя heatmap, pcolor или matshow или imshow, в данном случае мне не принципиально. Цветом будет обозначено значение параметра.

Но я столкнулся с трудностями, превращающими решение этой задачи в очень трудоемкую работу. Дело в том, что пропуск части данных в массиве связан с тем, что мое поле данных для отображения теплокарты не является прямоугольником, а на самом деле вписано в фигуру, приближающуюся по форме к кругу. Я присваиваю значения nan тем точкам в матрице данных, которые не принадлежат кругу. Т.е. в этой матрице значения nan имеют точки не относящиеся к условно говоря кругу, те же точки, которые образуют круг имеют вполне определенные значения параметра, которые я хотел бы отобразить цветом. Только некоторые столбцы и строки матрицы заполнены данными полностью. Т.е. таким способом я пытаюсь решить вопрос как можно отобразить теплокарту некоей произвольной формы, а не просто прямоугольник. На рисунке ниже представлено, что примерно я хочу получить.

[image: Пример необходимого результата]

В связи с этим у меня два вопроса.

1. При решении задачи с помощью моего подхода, какой параметр теплокарты может установить цвет по моему выбору для значений nan, поскольку белый цвет не всегда соответствует желаемому? Хотелось бы иметь возможность устанавливать его по своему выбору.
2. Более глобальный вопрос. Есть ли более простой способ построения графика-теплокарты, для которого я могу просто указать координаты x и y точек данных,
   и значения параметра (скажем z), которое будет преобразовано в цвет.  Чтобы не нужно было городить огород с созданием двумерного массива, с частью пропущенных данных, а просто закинуть array-like объекты x, y и z и получить такую теплокарту.  При этом этот график должен выглядеть как сплошное поле из прямоугольных плиточек, как показано на рисунке. А не как некий скаттерплот, с разноцветными точечками-маркерами.

В моем случае код, создающий график выглядит так:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

#Получение и преобразование данных...

#Формирование двумерного массива
data = create_matrix_data_vect(param_data=zamer_data.z_parameter, \
                            positions_data=positions_data_normal, \
                            data_shape=data_mass_shape)
data.shape
```

```
(12, 12) - размер может быть и намного больше
```

Массив данных выглядит так

```
array([[  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan, 201. , 195. , 203. , 196. ,   nan,
          nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan, 193. , 172. , 181. , 212. ,  91.3, 179. ,
          nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan, 188. , 208. , 180. , 201. , 239. , 243. , 254. ,
        253. ,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan, 232. , 234. , 224. , 266. , 263. , 258. , 218. , 215. ,
        200. , 192. ,   nan],
       [  nan, 211. , 201. , 194. , 190. , 199. , 196. , 187. , 200. ,
        199. , 192. ,   nan],
       [  nan, 200. , 202. , 207. , 201. , 195. , 203. , 196. , 193. ,
        172. , 181. ,   nan],
       [  nan, 212. ,  91.3, 179. , 188. , 208. , 180. , 201. , 239. ,
        243. , 254. ,   nan],
       [  nan, 253. , 232. , 234. , 224. , 266. , 263. , 258. , 218. ,
        215. , 200. ,   nan],
       [  nan, 192. , 211. , 201. , 194. , 190. , 199. , 196. , 187. ,
        200. , 199. ,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan, 192. , 200. , 202. , 207. , 201. , 195. , 203. ,
        196. ,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan, 193. , 172. , 181. , 212. ,  91.3, 179. ,
          nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan, 188. ,   nan,   nan, 208. ,   nan,
          nan,   nan,   nan]])
```

Для прорисовки графика используется примерно такой код:

```
bounds = np.linspace(param_ng, param_vg,continious_color_map.N)\  
.reshape(continious_color_map.N,)
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, continious_color_map.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (7, 7))
img = ax.matshow(data, cmap=continious_color_map, norm=norm)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size='5%', pad='1%')
fig.colorbar(img, cax=cax, ax=ax, ticks=bounds)
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели исходные данные. Навскидку, ничего трудного я не вижу - вы можете построить heatmap по трем значениям, создав mesh и воспользовавшись методом pcolormesh. О чем-то подобном написано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942700/plotting-a-heat-map-x-y-intensity-from-three-lists . Можно так же создать свою цветовую карту, если значения интенсивности вам известны: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626103/custom-colormap

Comment: Привел некоторые исходные данные

Answer (score 1):

На ваших исходных данных можно сделать так:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

arr = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 201., 195., 203., 196., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 193., 172., 181., 212.,  91.3, 179., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
       [np.nan, np.nan, 188., 208., 180., 201., 239., 243., 254., 253., np.nan, np.nan],
       [np.nan, 232., 234., 224., 266., 263., 258., 218., 215., 200., 192., np.nan],
       [np.nan, 211., 201., 194., 190., 199., 196., 187., 200., 199., 192., np.nan],
       [np.nan, 200., 202., 207., 201., 195., 203., 196., 193., 172., 181., np.nan],
       [np.nan, 212., 91.3, 179., 188., 208., 180., 201., 239., 243., 254., np.nan],
       [np.nan, 253., 232., 234., 224., 266., 263., 258., 218., 215., 200., np.nan],
       [np.nan, 192., 211., 201., 194., 190., 199., 196., 187., 200., 199., np.nan],
       [np.nan, np.nan, 192., 200., 202., 207., 201., 195., 203., 196., np.nan, np.nan],
       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 193., 172., 181., 212., 91.3, 179., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 188., np.nan, np.nan, 208., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])

X,Y = np.meshgrid(range(arr.shape[0]+1), range(arr.shape[1]+1))

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,arr)

plt.show()
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на тип `np.nan` в исходном списке и на начало координат на тепловой карте (у вас она перевернута). если вам нужно разместить начало координат именно в верхнем левом углу, добавьте `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` перед `plt.show()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а если вам нужен colorbar, то добавьте еще `plt.colorbar()` перед `plt.show()`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я поэкспериментирую с meshgrid и pcolormesh. Видимо этот подход был бы лучше. Я определил свой colorbar, мне нужен именно такой, как я сделал. Но вот как выбрать свой отдельный цвет для пропущенных значений тоже хотелось бы знать